# How pivotY and pivotX are calculated in android <rotate>

Tags: android, rotation, shapes

There are many articles how to make triangle as a shape. But nobody is explaining how pivotY and pivotX are calculated.
http://devdeeds.com/create-triangle-shape-using-xml-android/ (for example why android:pivotX="**-40%**" android:pivotY="**87%**"??? My logic expects 0% and 0% = left-top corner)

In the following code when I change **pivotX** the rectangle shape is moved **along Y** axis and when I change **pivotY - along X axis**.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item>
        <rotate
            android:fromDegrees="45"
            android:pivotX="0%"
            android:pivotY="50%"
            >
            <shape
                android:shape="rectangle">
                <solid android:color="#000000" />

            </shape>
        </rotate>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

I'm totally confused.

My final aim is to make diagonal triangles like on the picture below (gradient is easy to make http://angrytools.com/gradient/). If you pay attention the bottom triangle overflows screen width, therefore I cannot insert it as a bitmap and be sure it is displayed fine on all screen resolutions.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same problem. Since no units like `dp` are allowed in this attribute, it makes you wonder what unit is needed then.

From the `RotateDrawable` class:

```
if (a.hasValue(R.styleable.RotateDrawable_pivotX)) {
    final TypedValue tv = a.peekValue(R.styleable.RotateDrawable_pivotX);
    state.mPivotXRel = tv.type == TypedValue.TYPE_FRACTION;
    state.mPivotX = state.mPivotXRel ? tv.getFraction(1.0f, 1.0f) : tv.getFloat();
}
```

**onDraw()** of `RotateDrawable`:

```
final float px = st.mPivotXRel ? (w * st.mPivotX) : st.mPivotX;
canvas.rotate(st.mCurrentDegrees, px + bounds.left, py + bounds.top);
```

The source code of `RotateDrawable` shows: either the relative percentage value is needed, as you said, or a `float`.
In `onDraw()` of the class you can then see that simply this value is used directly for the call of `canvas.rotate()`, without being processed somehow, like `TypedValue.complexToDimension()` for instance.

So you can assume that also in the XML attribute **a value in pixels has to be used**, which just doesn't make any sense with vector drawables, because they can be scaled arbitrarily.

In my case it is a `VectorDrawable` with the size of `24dp` x `24dp`. The pivot point should be at (`12dp`|`19dp`). So I just used **12 of 24 = 50%** and **19 of 24 = 79.16%** as values for the pivot point of the `RotateDrawable`. To calculate this, you can use https://percentagecalculator.net/ for example. Then the pivot point is correct without having to try around a lot.

Comment: i just confused about the minimum & maximum value of pivot...

Comment: As you can see in my answer, I used percent values (don't forget the % sign), so it's from 0% to 100%. Values without a percent sign are handled as pixels, which is useless for vector graphics like icons. Instead calculate the percentage of hight and width of the pivot point.